# ARM instructions to C statements

Tags: c, assembly, arm

If I want to write a C statement equivalent to ARM assembly instructions:

```
mov r0, #2
```

Do I write it as a function? (i.e.):

```
myfunc1 
mov r0, #2 
bx lr
```

Or do I write it this way:

```
asm("mov r0, #2)
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It depends on your compiler, look up inline assembly in your compiler's documentation.

Comment: I am not trying to achieve anything yet, just trying to understand the syntax.

Comment: Are you trying to write assembly in C or are you looking for the rough C equivalent of assigning a constant to a variable?

Comment: I am trying to write assembly in C, ultimately would like to write a single C test program that calls each function & prints out the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing assembly inline for C depends on compiler extensions. How exactly you do it will be specific to the compiler you use.

For gcc, the [construct to use is](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#ss5.1)

```
   asm ( assembler template 
       : output operands                  /* optional */
       : input operands                   /* optional */
       : list of clobbered registers      /* optional */
       );
```

So, you're right, you use `asm("mov r0, #2")` if you use gcc.

However, you arbitrarily used `r0` and you don't tell your compiler that so your assembly code will conflict with the compiler's. You need to add `r0` to the clobber list so you compiler can save the register before calling your code if needed.

Comment: Using `r0` as the clobber works.  However, the *genius* of in-line assembler is to let the compiler allocate registers.  This is one of the most boring and error prone parts of *large scale* assembler programming.  Instead of `r0`, it is better to use the *output operands* and use `%0`; not to mention if you get things correct, the compiler will generate very good code and not put non-sense line before/after your in-line assembler.